# splicing time intervals posixct

Tags: r, time, posix, intervals

I have the following time intervals that I would like to split into 10 equally spaced instances.

```
head(data)
             stoptime           starttime
1 2014-08-19 14:52:04 2014-08-19 15:22:04
2 2014-08-19 16:27:14 2014-08-19 17:17:33
3 2014-08-19 18:05:59 2014-08-19 18:09:12
4 2014-08-19 17:25:35 2014-08-19 17:29:06
5 2014-08-19 18:23:29 2014-08-19 18:57:34
6 2014-08-19 07:39:15 2014-08-19 07:48:49
```

I am able to take the midpoint using this code

```
one_day$midtime = as.POSIXct((as.numeric(one_day$stoptime) + as.numeric(one_day$starttime)) /2 , origin = '1970-01-01')
```

however, when I try to extend this code to ten equally spaced instances it goes completely wrong.  Why is this happening and how can I fix this code?

```
one_day$first = as.POSIXct((as.numeric(one_day$stoptime) + as.numeric(one_day$starttime)) * .1 , origin = '1970-01-01')
one_day$second = as.POSIXct((as.numeric(one_day$stoptime) + as.numeric(one_day$starttime)) * .2, origin = '1970-01-01')
one_day$thrid = as.POSIXct((as.numeric(one_day$stoptime) + as.numeric(one_day$starttime)) * .3, origin = '1970-01-01')
one_day$fourth = as.POSIXct((as.numeric(one_day$stoptime) + as.numeric(one_day$starttime)) * .4, origin = '1970-01-01')
one_day$fifth = as.POSIXct((as.numeric(one_day$stoptime) + as.numeric(one_day$starttime)) * .5, origin = '1970-01-01')
one_day$sixth = as.POSIXct((as.numeric(one_day$stoptime) + as.numeric(one_day$starttime)) * .6, origin = '1970-01-01')
one_day$seventh = as.POSIXct((as.numeric(one_day$stoptime) + as.numeric(one_day$starttime)) * .7, origin = '1970-01-01')
one_day$eighth = as.POSIXct((as.numeric(one_day$stoptime) + as.numeric(one_day$starttime)) * .8, origin = '1970-01-01')
one_day$ninth = as.POSIXct((as.numeric(one_day$stoptime) + as.numeric(one_day$starttime)) * .9, origin = '1970-01-01')
```

```
head(one_day)
  diff.time            stoptime           starttime             midtime               first
1      1800 2014-08-19 14:52:04 2014-08-19 15:22:04 2014-08-19 15:07:04 1978-12-05 03:49:24
2      3019 2014-08-19 16:27:14 2014-08-19 17:17:33 2014-08-19 16:52:23 1978-12-05 04:10:28
3       193 2014-08-19 18:05:59 2014-08-19 18:09:12 2014-08-19 18:07:35 1978-12-05 04:25:31
4       211 2014-08-19 17:25:35 2014-08-19 17:29:06 2014-08-19 17:27:20 1978-12-05 04:17:28
5      2045 2014-08-19 18:23:29 2014-08-19 18:57:34 2014-08-19 18:40:31 1978-12-05 04:32:06
6       574 2014-08-19 07:39:15 2014-08-19 07:48:49 2014-08-19 07:44:02 1978-12-05 02:20:48
               second               thrid              fourth               fifth               sixth
1 1987-11-08 12:38:49 1996-10-11 21:28:14 2005-09-15 06:17:39 2014-08-19 15:07:04 2023-07-23 23:56:28
2 1987-11-08 13:20:57 1996-10-11 22:31:26 2005-09-15 07:41:54 2014-08-19 16:52:23 2023-07-24 02:02:52
3 1987-11-08 13:51:02 1996-10-11 23:16:33 2005-09-15 08:42:04 2014-08-19 18:07:35 2023-07-24 03:33:06
4 1987-11-08 13:34:56 1996-10-11 22:52:24 2005-09-15 08:09:52 2014-08-19 17:27:20 2023-07-24 02:44:48
5 1987-11-08 14:04:12 1996-10-11 23:36:18 2005-09-15 09:08:25 2014-08-19 18:40:31 2023-07-24 04:12:37
6 1987-11-08 09:41:36 1996-10-11 17:02:25 2005-09-15 00:23:13 2014-08-19 07:44:02 2023-07-23 15:04:50
              seventh              eighth               ninth
1 2032-06-26 08:45:53 2041-05-30 17:35:18 2050-05-04 02:24:43
2 2032-06-26 11:13:20 2041-05-30 20:23:49 2050-05-04 05:34:18
3 2032-06-26 12:58:37 2041-05-30 22:24:08 2050-05-04 07:49:39
4 2032-06-26 12:02:16 2041-05-30 21:19:44 2050-05-04 06:37:12
5 2032-06-26 13:44:44 2041-05-30 23:16:50 2050-05-04 08:48:56
6 2032-06-25 22:25:38 2041-05-30 05:46:27 2050-05-03 13:07:15
```

```
dput(data1)
structure(list(stoptime = structure(c(1408477924, 1408483634, 
1408489559, 1408487135, 1408490609, 1408451955, 1408452727, 1408498708, 
1408486644, 1408454996), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "EST"), 
    starttime = structure(c(1408479724, 1408486653, 1408489752, 
    1408487346, 1408492654, 1408452529, 1408455826, 1408501153, 
    1408488389, 1408458514), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "EST")), .Names = c("stoptime", 
"starttime"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: My answer is a little example. With a dput of your data I could consider to use your data. I am too lazy to try to copy and paste your data in my R :)

Answer (score 4):

### 1: Seq

First of all you have to convert the columns of your dataframe as POSIXct or POSIXlt class, because the r base function `seq` has a method for objects of that class.

Just see this semplified code:

```
library(lubridate)
a <- "2014-08-19 14:52:04"
b <- "2014-08-19 15:22:04"

a <- ymd_hms(a)
b <- ymd_hms(b)

a
[1] "2014-08-19 14:52:04 UTC"
b
[1] "2014-08-19 15:22:04 UTC"
```

Then you have to just use the `seq` function and set the parameters `length.out` with the value of the sequence you are seeking. The code will automatically create a sequence of values from the start to the end equally divided.

```
seq(a, b, length.out = 10)
[1] "2014-08-19 14:52:04 UTC" "2014-08-19 14:55:24 UTC"
[3] "2014-08-19 14:58:44 UTC" "2014-08-19 15:02:04 UTC"
[5] "2014-08-19 15:05:24 UTC" "2014-08-19 15:08:44 UTC"
[7] "2014-08-19 15:12:04 UTC" "2014-08-19 15:15:24 UTC"
[9] "2014-08-19 15:18:44 UTC" "2014-08-19 15:22:04 UTC"
```

### 2: Vectorize step 1

Now that you know how to achieve your goal, it is just a matter of trying how to vectorize it along values.

I bet there are several approaches, here is one. With the `mapply` function you can loop trough the elements and match the first element (of the first object) with the first element (of the second object) and so on. Keep in mind that you have to specify which parameters are fixed with the `MoreArg` arguments.

Here is the code:

```
mapply(seq,
       to = data1$starttime,
       from = data1$stoptime,
       MoreArgs = list(length.out = 10),
       SIMPLIFY = F)
```

that produces a list of your desired data but not in the desired format sadly:

```
[[1]]
 [1] "2014-08-19 14:52:04 UTC" "2014-08-19 14:55:24 UTC"
 [3] "2014-08-19 14:58:44 UTC" "2014-08-19 15:02:04 UTC"
 [5] "2014-08-19 15:05:24 UTC" "2014-08-19 15:08:44 UTC"
 [7] "2014-08-19 15:12:04 UTC" "2014-08-19 15:15:24 UTC"
 [9] "2014-08-19 15:18:44 UTC" "2014-08-19 15:22:04 UTC"

[[2]]
 [1] "2014-08-19 16:27:14 UTC" "2014-08-19 16:32:49 UTC"
 [3] "2014-08-19 16:38:24 UTC" "2014-08-19 16:44:00 UTC"
 [5] "2014-08-19 16:49:35 UTC" "2014-08-19 16:55:11 UTC"
 [7] "2014-08-19 17:00:46 UTC" "2014-08-19 17:06:22 UTC"
 [9] "2014-08-19 17:11:57 UTC" "2014-08-19 17:17:33 UTC"

[[3]]
 [1] "2014-08-19 18:05:59 UTC" "2014-08-19 18:06:20 UTC"
 [3] "2014-08-19 18:06:41 UTC" "2014-08-19 18:07:03 UTC"
 [5] "2014-08-19 18:07:24 UTC" "2014-08-19 18:07:46 UTC"
 [7] "2014-08-19 18:08:07 UTC" "2014-08-19 18:08:29 UTC"
 [9] "2014-08-19 18:08:50 UTC" "2014-08-19 18:09:12 UTC"

[[4]]
 [1] "2014-08-19 17:25:35 UTC" "2014-08-19 17:25:58 UTC"
 [3] "2014-08-19 17:26:21 UTC" "2014-08-19 17:26:45 UTC"
 [5] "2014-08-19 17:27:08 UTC" "2014-08-19 17:27:32 UTC"
 [7] "2014-08-19 17:27:55 UTC" "2014-08-19 17:28:19 UTC"
 [9] "2014-08-19 17:28:42 UTC" "2014-08-19 17:29:06 UTC"

[[5]]
 [1] "2014-08-19 18:23:29 UTC" "2014-08-19 18:27:16 UTC"
 [3] "2014-08-19 18:31:03 UTC" "2014-08-19 18:34:50 UTC"
 [5] "2014-08-19 18:38:37 UTC" "2014-08-19 18:42:25 UTC"
 [7] "2014-08-19 18:46:12 UTC" "2014-08-19 18:49:59 UTC"
 [9] "2014-08-19 18:53:46 UTC" "2014-08-19 18:57:34 UTC"

[[6]]
 [1] "2014-08-19 07:39:15 UTC" "2014-08-19 07:40:18 UTC"
 [3] "2014-08-19 07:41:22 UTC" "2014-08-19 07:42:26 UTC"
 [5] "2014-08-19 07:43:30 UTC" "2014-08-19 07:44:33 UTC"
 [7] "2014-08-19 07:45:37 UTC" "2014-08-19 07:46:41 UTC"
 [9] "2014-08-19 07:47:45 UTC" "2014-08-19 07:48:49 UTC"

[[7]]
 [1] "2014-08-19 07:52:07 UTC" "2014-08-19 07:57:51 UTC"
 [3] "2014-08-19 08:03:35 UTC" "2014-08-19 08:09:20 UTC"
 [5] "2014-08-19 08:15:04 UTC" "2014-08-19 08:20:48 UTC"
 [7] "2014-08-19 08:26:33 UTC" "2014-08-19 08:32:17 UTC"
 [9] "2014-08-19 08:38:01 UTC" "2014-08-19 08:43:46 UTC"

[[8]]
 [1] "2014-08-19 20:38:28 UTC" "2014-08-19 20:42:59 UTC"
 [3] "2014-08-19 20:47:31 UTC" "2014-08-19 20:52:03 UTC"
 [5] "2014-08-19 20:56:34 UTC" "2014-08-19 21:01:06 UTC"
 [7] "2014-08-19 21:05:38 UTC" "2014-08-19 21:10:09 UTC"
 [9] "2014-08-19 21:14:41 UTC" "2014-08-19 21:19:13 UTC"

[[9]]
 [1] "2014-08-19 17:17:24 UTC" "2014-08-19 17:20:37 UTC"
 [3] "2014-08-19 17:23:51 UTC" "2014-08-19 17:27:05 UTC"
 [5] "2014-08-19 17:30:19 UTC" "2014-08-19 17:33:33 UTC"
 [7] "2014-08-19 17:36:47 UTC" "2014-08-19 17:40:01 UTC"
 [9] "2014-08-19 17:43:15 UTC" "2014-08-19 17:46:29 UTC"

[[10]]
 [1] "2014-08-19 08:29:56 UTC" "2014-08-19 08:36:26 UTC"
 [3] "2014-08-19 08:42:57 UTC" "2014-08-19 08:49:28 UTC"
 [5] "2014-08-19 08:55:59 UTC" "2014-08-19 09:02:30 UTC"
 [7] "2014-08-19 09:09:01 UTC" "2014-08-19 09:15:32 UTC"
 [9] "2014-08-19 09:22:03 UTC" "2014-08-19 09:28:34 UTC"
```

At this point I guess it is just a matter of same data manipulation but I can't figure out a way (now).

Comment: thanks! how could that sequence by ordered into columns as I have in my data set?

Comment: `Error in seq.POSIXt(data$stoptime, data$starttime, length.out = 10) : 
  'from' must be of length 1` I get the following error when I input the data

Comment: The seq functions assume that from and to are single values, not vectors like you have.  Easiest would be to wrap this answer in a for loop for each row of your data

Answer (score 1):

You can't just multiply the time interval by 0.1, you have to add that 0.1 of the time interval to the earlier time.  For example:

```
one_day$firstexample = one_day$stoptime + 0.1*difftime(one_day$starttime, one_day$stoptime, units = "mins")
```

As a side note, if you find yourself typing out very similar things multiple times, that's usually a sign that you should turn it into a function.